# github pages white screen of death (404s) despite repository looking fine

Tags: github-pages

I have been going round and round in circles trying to work out why a deployment of my Angular app to Github pages is giving 404s even though I can see index.html and the missing files in the root of the gh-pages branch of the repository.

The repository (gh-pages branch which has been set up as the branch to use) is here: https://github.com/AngularianUK/parknow-pig-latin/tree/gh-pages

The URL for invoking gh pages is: https://angularianuk.github.io/parknow-pig-latin/

I see a 304 on the folder parknow-pig-latin and then 404s for all the chunked files that index.htm should be downloading.

If I add index.html manually to the end of the URL I get the ReadMe.md file for the site??!?

I have researched all the issues I could find (need for lower case index.html, need where source is in "dist" folder to remove that from gitignore and then git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages which seems to put the right dist subfolders in the repo but... 404s!

Can anybody give me a clue as to what's going wrong and what I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `<base href="/">` make your relative path go to https://angularianuk.github.io instead of https://angularianuk.github.io/parknow-pig-latin/.

You should remove `<base href="/">` or set it to `/parknow-pig-latin/`

The file to edit should be: `https://github.com/AngularianUK/parknow-pig-latin/blob/master/src/index.html`